# WebView & DOMS in VB.net

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net, dom, webview

Typically when using a WebControl we can take advantage of DOMS and "grab" specific text,full html, etc etc. with something like

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.All
    If Element.GetAttribute("SomeClassName") = "h1" Then
        'Do Something here.
        Exit For 'Stop looping.
    End If
Next
```

however I am now working with WebView (1; Edge) {At least until WebView2 is no longer a pre-release and WebView becomes obsolete}. I have tried firing JavaScript

```
webview1.InvokeScript("JavaScriptFunctionHere")
```

Where JavaScriptFunction was

"document.getElementById('jsx-2835528490').innerText;"

I created a sub (and tested a function to see if I can return the string)

```
Private Async Function GetHtml() As Task(Of String)
        Dim functionString = String.Format("document.getElementsByClassName('jsx-2835528490').innerText;")
        Await WebView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", New String() {functionString})
        ' Return Await WebView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", New String() {functionString})
End Function
```

If you look in the "Function (which I had as a sun as well when I didn't need to return the string)you will notice "Return"

What I am attempting to do is use a WebView (as a more modern solution) to use DOMS to get the innerText of the ONLY Element in the HTML that is between  and is in the "div" and "h5" both have the the className "jsx-2835528490"

Nothing I try in the WebView is working. I really would like to use Webview over webControl for many reasons but the main reason is the website wont load properly in webControl anyway because the website is built with a HTML5 Standard that isn't supported entirely by IE

Outside of AgilityPack (for a few reasons) Only using DOMS within a WebView control can anyone think of a way to do this?

While there is plenty of Documentation by Microsoft in regards to Clicking a button with Webview and a few other useful methods/events ; There is nothing specifically on Returning the String from the getElements unless it's just my JS that is off as well?

Note: I have also checked StackOverflow as thoroughly as I could for a solution. Normally even these "newer" questions get attention and can be resolved I was shocked not to find an answer among the rest of the tremendous help here.

Thank you again! For any Help! Even a "Point in the right direction"

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is Curious. The issue was my JS {a bit}

```
Dim name As String = Await WebView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", New String() {"document.getElementsByClassName('jsx-2835528490')[0].innerText.toString();"})
```

This works fine.

Then you can just pass "name" to wherever you need it to.